# Python module tkinter :what is best practice and way to access all its class

Tags: python, tkinter

**Issue description:**
Please see following two example of Code A and Code B.

1. Code A:

   ```py
   from tkinter import messagebox
   messagebox.showinfo("Hello ")
   ```
2. Code B:

   ```py
   from tkinter import *
   tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Hello ")
   ```

**Question :**
Why Code B doesn't work?

(I do not want to get confused on using short form tk,I am ok writing tkinter)

Comment: Still not clear why code B cant work, can u pls elaborate only on the code above, will appreciate it.Thank you..Vi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is correct for the messagebox.

As with many python packages, not all functionality is automatically imported. Some, such as the messagebox and font modules, must be explicitly imported.

In the second case, you should not use wildcard imports. Even though a lot of tkinter tutorials import tkinter this way, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the standard and it discourages wildcard imports.

While it will indeed import many of the tkinter classes and variables, it still won't import the messagebox module.

Comment: why sir it will not import message box module, since its "*", I am trying to find how to make code B work, just for understanding (I will not use that practice just to understand the process)

Comment: @Visharma: like the answer says, "not all functionality is automatically imported". That's just how some packages work. "code B" will never work. You must import `messagebox` separately.

Comment: Thx for reply sir.. best Vi